# Process builder check for specific user

Tags: formula, process-builder, conditional, compile-error

I want my process builder conditions to update for all users except for one particular user.  There is not a User option, only Owner and Profile.  But the Owner of an object does not mean another user can not come in and make an update. 
 How would I check for the current user that is trying to make an update?

```
[ACCOUNT].Owner.Profile.Name ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot reference values related to the running context and user in Process Builder criteria, but you *can* get to them if you set actions to execute if a formula evaluates to true. There, you can click the "System Values" search box to get access to a tree of data sourced from the running context:

[image: PB screenshot]

While you can add formula references here to the User, their Role, or their Profile, for circumstances like the one you describe the superior solution is usually to create a new [Custom Permission](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_perms_overview.htm&type=5) and check for that (the "Permission" value tree in the screenshot above).

This allows you to make changes to the behavior administratively, by adding and removing a permission set from a user, rather than by deploying or changing your Process Builder. It's more resilient to changes in your org and desired business process.

A similar process can be used for a Hierarchy Custom Setting.

Comment: is there a way to set a permission set, so they can not trigger the process builder?  The user has to update the object just not specific fields.

Comment: Not a permission set, a Custom Permission. You can apply Custom Permissions to specific users *via* a permission set.

Comment: @David Can you please help me with this question https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/309032/prcocess-builder-to-check-on-the-profile-is-not-working-as-expected I followed the formula set to true but it doesnt work not sure if I am missing something

Comment: Please let the community engage on your question - we have a lot of highly expert users and request that folks not tag in specific users.

Comment: @DavidReed Sure just tagged because I tried to follow the solution you specified